# Using an interface inside onScrollListener

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-recyclerview

I have an activity with a recyclerview, which lists 10 emails when the activity starts (this part works fine). I'm using asynctask to get the data with javamail API. Also, since the asynctask is in a seperate class and not nested, I used an interface to delegate the onPostExecude to my activity with the recview. 
BUT I also need to implement a function that if I'm at the bottom of the list, I load 10 more emails with asynctask again. (only 10 at a time since it takes time to load these) I'm having problem with the asnyctask delegate part when I'm inside the listener:

**Email_InboxActivity class:**

```
public class Email_InboxActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements fetchInboxMail_Interface {

private String email, password, providerName, imapHostName;
private boolean isThereMore = true;
private RecyclerView recList;
private LinearLayoutManager llm;
private fetchInboxMail mAsyncTask;
private fetchInboxMail_Interface mInterface;
public ArrayList<Email_Message> loadedEmails = new ArrayList<Email_Message>();
int firstVisibleItem, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount, startIndex = 0, offset = 10;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_email__inbox);
    ...

    //setting up the recyclerview
    recList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.email_list);
    recList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recList.setLayoutManager(llm);

    recList.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

            visibleItemCount = llm.getChildCount();
            totalItemCount = llm.getItemCount();
            firstVisibleItem = llm.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();


            if(isThereMore && totalItemCount == (firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount) && visibleItemCount > 0 ){
                mAsyncTask = new fetchInboxMail(Email_InboxActivity.this, email, password, imapHostName, startIndex, offset);
                mAsyncTask.execute();
                mAsyncTask.delegate = mInterFace //nullpoint exception, and the keyword "this" also not working since this class doesnt implement the interface
            }
        }
    });

    mAsyncTask = new fetchInboxMail(Email_InboxActivity.this, email, password, imapHostName, startIndex, offset);
    mAsyncTask.execute();
    mAsyncTask.delegate = this;
}

...

public void AsyncTaskFinish(ArrayList<Email_Message> EmailInbox){
    loadedEmails.addAll(EmailInbox);
    Email_ListAdapter mAdapter = new Email_ListAdapter(loadedEmails);
    recList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    startIndex = loadedEmails.size();

    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("isthere_more_email", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    isThereMore = sharedPref.getBoolean("isthere_more", true);
    if(!isThereMore){
        Toast.makeText(Email_InboxActivity.this, getString(R.string.last_email_toast), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
}
```

**The interface:**

```
public interface fetchInboxMail_Interface {

void AsyncTaskFinish(ArrayList<Email_Message> EmailInbox);
}
```

edit: **asynctask onpostexecute part:**

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Email_Message> EmailInbox) {
    super.onPostExecute(EmailInbox);

    ...
    delegate.AsyncTaskFinish(EmailInbox);
}
```

So what's the solution so I can use the interface in the onScrollListener too? I thought about making a new class that extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() and implements the interface, but the problem is that I dont have the fields I need in that class (loadedEmails, recList, llm).

I would be very sad if the anwser is that I need to use the asynctask as a nested class and drop the interface :(

Comment: Whats your problem, your solution looks like should work, can you post your asynctask code?

Comment: That really doesnt matter I think, but I guess i can add in the onpostexecute part. The problem is in the onscrolllistener, where the comment is. That line gives nullpointexception at the moment.

Comment: `mAsyncTask.execute();`
`mAsyncTask.delegate = this;`
I would swap those two lines
If asynctask finishes synchronously the delegate will be null

Comment: its not possible that this line is throwing a nullpointer, ist not calling any method. You should not need to store a reference to itself, if mInterface will be always equal to this why storing it?, also, where are you setting it?

Comment: @eyeballz it should not, but anyway its better to prevent it, just in case of.

Comment: @Nanoc Nowhere, I'm having a problem with what to write there. It worked outside of the listener, since the activity implements the interface, but I cant do the same with the listener to my knowledge. At least not as a nested class. The only solution i can think of is use the asynctask as a nested class in the activity but i really want to avoid that, i'm looking for alternatives, I'm not sure if there's one.

Comment: So you are looking for mAsyncTask.delegate = Email_InboxActivity.this?

Comment: Yes I do :D Maaan I always miss an obvious solution (it shows that I'm kinda new to this still). Thank you, it works fine now! If you answer the question I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change this line:

```
mAsyncTask.delegate = mInterFace;
```

to

```
mAsyncTask.delegate = Email_InboxActivity.this;
```

Also you could do

```
mInterface = this;
```

in the OnCreate method, but anyway it has no sense to store a reference to itself where you can just use this.

Hope this helps.